# IOS Deployment with Ionic

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework

Is it possible to deploy an ionic app to your ios device without publishing it on the app store? I do have a Mac and a developers license, the app I want to use is for private use (for about 5 users).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course, you just need Xcode to generate the ipa so you can install it anywhere.

Check this guide: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/index.html As ionic is essentially cordova the steps are similar.

Answer (score 19):

Yes, indeed you can.

You first have to build your project for ios:

```
ionic build ios
```

Then you have to open up (with Xcode) the .xproj project that was generated by `ionic build ios` command (you'll see the exact location in the command's output).

Now you have to connect your iPhone to you Mac computer and you'll be able to choose your iPhone as a "deployment" device.

Click run in Xcode and after the Xcode finishes guiding you through creating a provisioning profile you'll have the app on your phone.

For more info take a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html

Comment: Thanks. It adds the <project name>.xcodeproj file  to the <project name>/platforms/ios folder

Comment: I think you should run not build.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to upload ipa to App Store and Device (ionic App)

Step 1 
1.  Import Project to Mac Laptop
2.  Create a new Project in Mac via terminal and import all SRC Folder from old project to new Project.
3.  Open the New Project.
4.  Copy the Dependency from old Projects from Dependencies and paste in New Project in Dependencies
5.  Don’t remove old Dependency of new Project just install new one
6.  Fire command Npm install once dependency and Src Folder is copied to new Project 
7.  Go to config.xml change widget id, version, Description, author email, href.
8.  Change Version in package-lock.json
9.  Npm install
10.  Don’t Forget to Save All Files.

Step 2 
1.  Ionic serve -l
If you have installed Native Plugins (I.e. camera, network, base 64 etc.), Reinstall that All Native Plugins.
2.  Verify that app is running in browser
3.  Ionic cordova build ios

Step 3
1.  Go to developer.apple.com
2.  Click on Identifier-> App Id. 
3.  Register App Id Name and Bundle Id
4.  Click on Continue and Register
5.  Go to Provisional Profile 
6.  Click + Sign
7.  Click on Development 
8.  Select Ios App Development
9.  Select IPhone Listed
10. Generate Profile Name by Giving Name
11. Continue and Profile will be Ready 
12. Click on Done.

Step 4
1.  Go to Project-> ios-> projectName.xcodeproj 
2.  Xcode will be opened when you open file projectName.xcodeproj
3.  Click on Project and Automatic Signing
4.  Select your Device and Click on Run Button
5.  Change Bundle Name and Bundle Identifier Name in INFO
6.  File -> Project Setting ->Shared Project Setting -> Build Setting ->Select Legacy Build System instead of Default (Verify Once)
7.  Click on Run Button Your App will be Deployed in iPhone